# RabbitMQ Does each user need credentials to connect with the broker?

Tags: php, rabbitmq

So, I'm currently trying to figure out, if I'll have to create a new user for the broker everytime someone registers for my chatting platform.

Since the AMQPStreamConnection requires a user and a pass, which is by default guest, guest. Or should I just create a general user, with which all the platform users are going to connect with. This one will obviously have less rights than the admin, since this general user is only meant for normal chatting.

Comment: Ideally, no. Your *application* should handle user authentication/authorization and then set up connections to the relevant RMQ queues using the application's RMQ credentials. Offloading all user auth to RMQ sounds like a nightmare in the making.

Comment: So setting up one pair of RMQ credentials that is being used by all users to connect to the stream after the applications auth. process is correct?

Comment: I think this is a bit of a broad question dealing primarily with application architecture. As a general rule, you don't want your back-end infrastructure exposed to the wide-open world. It is best to have a service layer protecting your back-end.